# Customize the Android Seekbar

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am going to customize the Seekbar in Android and I am having one problem with it.

This is what I am going to do : [image]

This is now I get :

[image: currnet]

And Here is my code:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/blueSlider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        android:maxHeight="40dp"
        android:shape="oval"
        android:thumbOffset="-20dp"
        android:secondaryProgress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styled_progress"
        android:max="@integer/slider_max_value"
        android:thumb="@drawable/oval_seekbar_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/blueText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

styled_progress.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="25dp"/>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/gradient_start"
                android:endColor="@color/gradient_end"
                android:angle="0" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners
                    android:radius="90dp"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

oval_seekbar_thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <size android:height="25dp" android:width="25dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Please help me on this problem.(missing white line)
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try adding a margin around your secondary progress

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <!--    BACKGROUND-->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="25dp"/>
            <size android:height="30dp"
                android:width="200dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/primary"
                android:endColor="@color/primary_light"
                android:angle="0" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="14dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="14dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Angel Koh.
It is really what I was going to do.